# For multiple listviews using one custom adapter

Tags: android, listview

Actually i am creating multiple listviews using single custom adapter using for loop what the issue when pass array list into adapter after that it is loading last sent array list to all list views and here below is my code , please help me as i am new to android.

```
for (int iqs=0; iqs< invoiceList.size();iqs++){
    invoice1 = invoiceList.get(iqs);
    itemsList1.clear();
    loadListViews(invoice1, listView1);//here am getting itemlist1 arraylist
    adapter=  new CustomAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this, itemsList1);

    listView1 = new ListView(this);
    listView1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(headerWidth, listHeight));
    //  listView1.setLayoutParams(list1Params);
    listView1.setDivider(null);
    listView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#defbff"));
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    linear1.addView(listView1);
}
```

here is my adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater inflator;
private ArrayList<ItemsBean> newList = null;
private Context ctx;

DbHelperCozyPos dbHelper;
ArrayList<ItemsBean> disablelist = new ArrayList<ItemsBean>();
String parentobjid=null;

public CustomAdapter(Context ctx,int i,ArrayList<ItemsBean> invoiceDataList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.newList = invoiceDataList;
    this.inflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return newList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return newList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public  class ViewHolder {
    TextView qty, name;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final ViewHolder holder;
    convertView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.invoicelistadapter, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(newList.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
    holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newList.get(position).getQuantityDisplay()));
    holder.name.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    holder.name.setTextSize(Constants.listbody);
    holder.qty.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0e1644"));
    holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0e1644"));
}
```

new list click listner code;

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(ctx, ""+ "hii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ctx);
                            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itembumping);
                            dialog.setCancelable(false);
                            dialog.show();
            ListView    list1=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.list1);
            ItemBumpingAdapter adapter2 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(ctx,newList);
                    list1.setAdapter(adapter2);

        }
    });
```

Comment: The thing is, you can have only one `CustomAdapter` like now, but for every list view, you should create a new object of this adapter and pass the new adapter to your `listView`.

Comment: for mu;ltiple listviews how can i create multiple adapters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your code with this.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater inflator;
private ArrayList<ItemsBean> newList = null;
private Context ctx;

DbHelperCozyPos dbHelper;
ArrayList<ItemsBean> disablelist = new ArrayList<ItemsBean>();
String parentobjid=null;

public CustomAdapter(Context ctx,int i,ArrayList<ItemsBean> invoiceDataList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.newList = new ArrayList<>(invoiceDataList);

    this.inflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return newList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return newList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public  class ViewHolder {
    TextView qty, name;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final ViewHolder holder;
    convertView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.invoicelistadapter, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(newList.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
    holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newList.get(position).getQuantityDisplay()));
    holder.name.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    holder.name.setTextSize(Constants.listbody);
    holder.qty.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0e1644"));
    holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0e1644"));
}
```

Comment: hii, here in adapter eachitem is loading 5 times , it reduces the performance what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You must sent type to your adapter that demonstrate which layout must be inflate and inflate approach layout.

Comment: means? i didnt understand